# How to use gluUnproject?

Tags: python, opengl, matrix

I am working on an OpenGL project where I need to be able to click on stuff in 3D space. As far as I can tell gluUnproject() will do that job. But I have heard unexpected things might happen, and the accuracy will be thrown off. It could just be that these people used it wrong, or something else. Is there anything unusual I should know about gluUnproject()?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*I once asked a question, which contains what you seem to be searching, [click here to see my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18244678/3d-ray-picking-use-mouse-coordinates-when-mouse-isnt-locked).*

But basically what you can use `gluUnproject()` for is to calculate 2D Screen Coordinates (Probably Mouse Coordinates) to 3D World Space Coordinates.

Then you can calculate two points. The first point could be the point on the near plane and the second point could be at the far plane, thereby you can create a line which you then can use to perform collision detection with.

[image]

The above images comes from a post ([click here to see the post](http://www.bfilipek.com/2012/06/select-mouse-opengl.html)), the post actually describes and tells about probably what you seem to be seeking.